# Usando function dentro de Select

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um select, dentro dele tenho uma função :

```
SELECT VAL1, VAL2, ".funcao('VAL1', 'VAL2')." AS soma FROM Conta WHERE soma < 100
```

Estrutura da tabela `CONTA`

```
--------------------
| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
--------------------
| 1  |  10  |  50  |
--------------------
| 2  |  50  |  80  |
--------------------
| 3  |  30  |  70  |
--------------------
```

Se eu usar a seguinte estrutura na função :

```
function funcao($valor1, $valor2)
    { 
        $retorno = $valor1 + $valor2;
        return $retorno; 
    };
```

Consigo retornar o valor de cada coluna numa boa, e ainda obtenho o resultado!

Dai tentei trabalhar mais a função e aplicar o valor dentro de uma string. Ex:

```
function funcao($valor1, $valor2)
    { 
        $res = "Os números a ser somados são ".$valor1." e ".$valor2."";
        echo $res ;

        //Esse echo serve apenas de exemplo, pra mostrar o retorno da variável 
    };
```

Só que isso eu não conseguir fazer! Quando apliquei a variável `$valor1` ou `$valor2`, em vez de mostrar o valor referente a coluna, ele mostrou o próprio nome da coluna, ou seja, `VAL1` e `VAL2`

> Minha dúvida é
>
> > É possível trabalhar com essas variáveis em uma função mais complexa de acordo com o exemplo citado, sem que se perca o valor da coluna? Já que quando eu tento fazer isso o valor fica como "VAL1" em vez de 10 ou 50.

Em modo mais simples! Mesmo que eu queira simplesmente fazer um "echo $valor1" dentro da função, o resultado é "VAL1" em vez de "10"

Comment: Tente entender que a parte do Select acontece no MySQL, e não no PHP. Se você puser a função na hora de gerar a query, ela é processada ANTES do MySQL começar a trabalhar (antes mesmo dele ter os dados para processar). No MySQL só funciona código SQL, e não PHP. Depois que os dados voltam do SELECT, aí dá pra usar PHP de novo, mas não é na _query_ (que é o ultimo exemplo que eu dei).

Comment: No mesmo paragrafo que você marcou em negrito, você explicou de forma direta como a função vai ser executada, ou seja, primeiro vai pegar o valor da função pra só depois executar o select em conjunto! E isso esclareceu bem!

Comment: No caso, 'VAL1' e 'VAL2' pro PHP tem um sentido completamente diferente, são meras strings. Quando você faz `funcao( 'VAL1', 'VAL2' )` está mandando dois "textos" para a função, por isso o echo mostra exatamente iguais. Vou apagando os comentários de cima, que você já leu, pra nao ficar muita bagunça na sua pergunta.

Comment: Sim! Entendi essa parte! Por isso alterei a pergunta, e por isso aceitei ela! Porque agora entendi o processo! - Achava que VAL1 e VAL2 já estava com seu resultado! Só que pelo que entendi, no momento que a função é executada o Select nem aconteceu ainda! -eu achava o contrario! Que estava começando o select, depois a função e que depois desse processo eu estava perdendo os valores

Comment: Talvez um caminho seja aprender as funções do MySQL e testar separadamente no banco (usando o MySQL Workbench, ou ferramenta similar) para treinar a fazer operaçoes no DB diretamente (esquecendo um pouco o PHP). Meu medo é só você acabar confundindo mais, kkkk. Talvez seja bom dar uma "treinada" nas funções do PHP e nos parâmetros antes. Mas quando achar que é a hora, um resumo das funções do MySQL está aqui: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions.html

Comment: Eu até cheguei ver um exemplo de uma pergunta no stackoverflow em inglês que o cara usou a função própria do MySQL. Mas agora sim eu entendi o porque!

Comment: Dá pra brincar um pouco com o SQL Fiddle, se quiser testar. Montei um teste aplicando o que pus na resposta: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14b055/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Veja a aplicação do seu código:

```
query( "SELECT VAL1, VAL2, ".funcao('VAL1', 'VAL2')." AS soma FROM Conta WHERE soma < 100" );
```

Neste caso, o PHP vai juntar estas três coisas, pois você usou o operador de concatenação (`.`):

- `"SELECT VAL1, VAL2, "`
- `funcao('VAL1', 'VAL2')`
- `" AS soma FROM Conta WHERE soma < 100"`

A primeira e a última são strings. A do meio, é uma chamada de função. Então, o PHP vai obter seu valor antes de concatenar, chamando sua função com duas *strings*, que são `'VAL1'` e `'VAL2'`, resultando em zero, que é a soma **das duas *strings* que você passou no seu exemplo**, que não tem relação nenhuma com os valores do `SELECT` (que sequer aconteceu ainda).

Então o resultado será esse:

```
query( "SELECT VAL1, VAL2, 0 AS soma FROM Conta WHERE soma < 100" );
```

Só depois de concatenada a *string* no PHP, ela será enviada para o MySQL.

No segundo exemplo a coisa fica mais evidente:

```
function funcao($valor1, $valor2)
{ 
    $res = "Os números a ser somados são ".$valor1." e ".$valor2."";
    echo $res ;
};
```

Cpomo não tem `return` na função, só `echo`, fica mais fácil de perceber que 'VAR1' e 'VAR2' são somente *strings* para o PHP, portanto saem na tela como foram enviadas. E mesmo que pusesse um `return`, a *string* final não seria um SQL válido.

### Solução

Se você quer usar funções no lado do DB, precisa que as funções sejam as do SQL, e não do PHP. Exemplo:

```
query( "SELECT VAL1, VAL2, VAL1+VAL2 AS soma FROM Conta WHERE soma < 100" );
```

Outro exemplo, com *strings* **do lado do SQL**:

```
query( "SELECT VAL1, VAL2, CONCAT( "Resultado:", VAL1+VAL2, "rea ) AS soma FROM Conta" );
```

Outra possibilidade seria pegar todo o resultado em um *array*, e depois fazer um loop no PHP chamando sua função (desta vez em PHP). Isto poderia ser feito na hora de mostrar os valores na tela.

Exemplo:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
    echo $row['VAL1'].' somado com '.$row['VAL2'].' resulta em '.($row['VAL1']+$row['VAL2']);
}
```